# Migration failes after running CREATE DB IF NOT EXIST

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I am using Laravel 8 with sail. I want to create a command that creates multiple databases (I want to use the [parallel tests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/testing#running-tests-in-parallel) feature together with DatabaseTransaction trait, so a migration once beforehand is required. Migration takes also a long time, so creation during test won't work for me).

This is how I create a database and then migrate it in my command:

```
$database='mydb_test_1';
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', null);
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;";
DB::statement($query);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $database);
// Necessary to update database name, as DB is a singleton
DB::reconnect();
$this->call('migrate');
```

This peace of code works for the very first time, when the database did not exist yet.

However, if I run it twice, it shows this error:

[image]

However, if I disable the `DB:statement(..)` like this:

```
$database='mydb_test_1';
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', null);
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;";
//DB::statement($query);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $database);
// Necessary to update database name, as DB is a singleton
DB::reconnect();
$this->call('migrate');
```

Then the code from above returns

> Nothing to migrate.

no matter how often I call it.

Why is that? Why does `DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ..');` makes the migration command fail?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->call('migrate:fresh');
```

but this command initially deletes all tables from the database and then migrates again

Comment: Yes that would work. But I am trying to find out why "migrate" itself does not work. Whats the reason for the error?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you imported the database and ran the command or changed the name of the migration, then it should give such an error, but I'm not sure. When I have such an error, I usually clear the database if there is no data in it

Comment: Yes, thats the typical scenario  when one screws up the database, or a migration was failed and already added table/column but did not finish. But here its different. If I run "artisan migrate" on CLI I get "Nothing to migrate", so the table/migration is fine. It just failes if I run the DB::statement from above.